# SQL Server Msg 511 error on a SELECT statement

Tags: sql-server

I am getting this message while doing a SELECT statement.

> Msg 511, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
>   Cannot create a row of size 8274 which is greater than the allowable maximum row size of 8060.

Curious, if my SELECT is coded as below - the error occurs:

```
SELECT   
    EDGC01.*, EDGC02.*, ATT.*
```

But if I code (with the "top 1000") it works:

```
SELECT TOP 1000 
    EDGC01.*, EDGC02.*, ATT.*
```

Only 295 rows are returned.

This is on a SQL Server 2016 environment.

Comment: I suspect I'll regret asking, but how many columns are in your table? please post your table schema definition

Comment: @MitchWheat Obviously the answer is "way too many"!

Comment: You shouldn't return all the columns if you don't need them, but you are only getting the error when one or more of the returned rows contains too much data.

Comment: To quote the OP from a topic they've also made on [SSC](https://www.sqlservercentral.com/Forums/1933429/SQL-511-error-on-a-SELECT-statement#bm1933445): *"Yes, the tables are very wide. There are a total of 932 columns returned when the SQL works. There is a different execution plan when the top 1000 is used vs. when it's not included."* So, @DavidG , you were right. Way way way too many. :)

Comment: @Larnu Jeeeeeebus! If a dev working for me came to me with a table with more than 50 columns, I'd send them away to think about what they'd done. For 932, I'd consider ritual sacrifice.

Comment: Seems you were right to regret asking @MitchWheat...

Comment: @ DavidG: If a dev in my team came to me with a table with more than 100 columns, I'd reach for the cattle prod. Am I being too lenient?